# Live preview sem precisar salvar no Brackets

Tags: editor-de-texto

Segundo a apresentação do editor Brackets, com a função Live Preview as alterações no código sempre serão visualizadas em tempo real, sem a necessidade de salvar o documento.

No meu editor, tenho que salvar para que seja visualizado no navegador. Como configuro para que seja em tempo real ?